# RiotJS: How to cache values during loops?

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I'm looking to improve performance and readability by caching repeated values during `each={}` loops in [RiotJS](http://riotjs.com). Is there a way to do so that will not render the value and/or incur unnecessary performance overhead?

Before:

```
<my-tag>
  <p each="{item in data}">
    <b if="{item.style == 'b'}">{item.text}</b>
    <i if="{item.style == 'i'}">{item.text}</i>
  </p>
  data = [
    {"text": "bold me", "style": "b"},
    {"text": "italicize me", "style": "i"}
  ];
</my-tag>

<!-- Renders <p><b>bold me</b></p> <p><i>italicize me</i></p> -->
```

After:

```
<my-tag>
  <p each="{item in data}">
    {style=item.style}
    {text=item.text}
    <b if="{style == 'b'}">{text}</b>
    <i if="{style == 'i'}">{text}</i>
  </p>
  data = [
    {"text": "bold me", "style": "b"},
    {"text": "italicize me", "style": "i"}
  ];
</my-tag>

<!-- Renders <p>b bold me <b>bold me</b></p> <p>i italicize me <i>italicize me</i></p> -->
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3s398a1z/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do that :

```
<p each="{data}">
  <b if="{style == 'b'}">{text}</b>
  <i if="{style == 'i'}">{text}</i>
</p>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3s398a1z/1/)

Comment: This won't cover my use case, as I'm looking for more complex behavior: `{cell = parent.row[column.key]} <td if="{cell.type == 'text'}">{cell.content}</td>`, etc. Fairly sure the "proper" answer is to use a pre-render function to re-structure the data to match the DOM hierarchy; I was just hoping there was a clean way to do the same thing inline.

Comment: I understand, I think it's a good idea to convert your data to an easier structure.

Answer (score 0):

The following has bugs on 2.5, but works great on the [next](https://github.com/riot/riot/tree/next) branch (3.0.0-alpha.5):

```
<my-tag>
  <p each="{item in data}">
    {(style=item.style) && false}
    {(text=item.text) && false}
    <b if="{style == 'b'}">{text}</b>
    <i if="{style == 'i'}">{text}</i>
  </p>
  data = [
    {"text": "bold me", "style": "b"},
    {"text": "italicize me", "style": "i"}
  ];
</my-tag>
```

Because the expressions evaluate to false, they don't render, but the values of `style` and `text` still get set.